# Speeding up a MySQL Query with Counting Distinct Rows and Left Joins

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join, database-performance

I'm trying to get a list of all the bands in the database a long with the number of songs and albums associated with each band. The song table is ~18,000 lines, the album table is ~3,000 lines, and the bands table is ~1,200 lines. I have indexes on BandID in both the albums and songs tables, but this query still takes about 26 seconds to run! Is there a better/faster way to get all of this information in one query?

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
SELECT b.ID, b.Name, b.URL, b.Alpha, b.Sort, b.Image, b.Path, COUNT(DISTINCT s.ID) AS SongCount, COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID) AS AlbumCount FROM mft_bands AS b
        LEFT JOIN mft_albums AS a ON a.BandID = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN mft_songs AS s ON s.BandID = b.ID
        WHERE b.Enabled=1 GROUP BY b.ID ORDER BY b.Name
```

Comment: Silly Question..  Do you have to use the LEFT JOIN?  Can you use just a JOIN to achieve the same result?  Notice you are using a DISTINCT in your Song and Album..  Why?  An individual Band is only going to have distinct albums and songs..  Could there be the same song / album between bands, sure..

Comment: I can just make them joins I suppose, but it doesn't speed it up at all. I need to set the distinct or I get the same number of albums as songs. Setting distinct is the only way I could figure out how to count two different joined variables.